# Run pending seeders

Tags: sequelize.js, seed, sequelize-cli

I'm going to store seeder history into `sequelizedata` table. 
Is there a way to run pending seeders?

Right now, regarding to `sequelize --help` there is only:

- `db:seed` - runs specific seeder
- `db:seed:all` - runs all seeders

Neither of both are working

[image: sequelizeError]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that problem by removing `done` argument from last seeder file.

```js
'use strict'

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize, done) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert(
      'table_name',
      data,
      {}
    )
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    queryInterface.bulkDelete('table_name', null, {}),
}
```